# Adding additional data to a model

Tags: machine-learning

I'm currently running a logistic regression for classification on 100 patients dataset. However for 10 of those patients I have additional data that would help the accuracy for for those 10 patients. I was thinking of producing two models, one for all 100 and then one for 10,then using the 10 patients model whenever there is data for it. Though this seems not optimal, I was wondering if there are other ways to do this, I'm sure this problem arises quite often.

Comment: In what sense do you have "additional data" for those 10 samples? Do you mean you have data for variables, say, X1-X3 for all, but also X4 for those 10?

Comment: Yes this is precisely what I mean in this simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend the approach of two different models. If the data is missing from the 90 while present and predictive in the 10, this creates a significant bias that jeopardizes external validity of the model(s).

Comment: I agree. Though the only other way I can incorporate the additional data is via imputation. But with such a high missing rate, it would be incorrect. How about getting the probability from the logistic regression from 100 patient model then feeding it to the 10 patient model.